# why does my Entity Framework keep downgrading from 6.4.4 to 6.1.3?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

so me and my team work on azure dev-ops and so, everytime we commit a task the Entity Framework downgrades to 6.1.3.

Does anyone have the same issue? if yes and you have fixed it can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

A year after your post I have been having the same issue. Entity Framework version 6.4.4 kept downgrading to 6.1.3.

I had deprecated OWIN packages. Since updating these to the latest stable (admittedly a big jump), I have not had an issue with EF automatically downgrading.

I'm guessing it kept downgrading to remain compatible with the old OWIN libraries.